# how to use etree.write() to output a xml file that doesn't have default ns?

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing, elementtree

So I have a xml file that needs some change. After modification, I want to write the new content to a new file, output.xml. I used the write() method, but I get a lot ns# in front of each line. I figured how to get rid of all these ns# by using _namespace_map, but how do you preserve the previous xmlns? For example, the original xml file is :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">

    <extensions>
    </extensions>

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0">
        </subsystem>
    </profile>

</server>
```

Currently what I'm getting:

```
<ns0:server xmlns:ns0="urn:jboss:domain:1.2" xmlns:ns1="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1" xmlns:ns2="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0">

    <ns0:extensions>
    </ns0:extensions>

    <ns0:profile>
        <ns1:subsystem>
        </ns1:subsystem>
        <ns2:subsystem>
        </ns2:subsystem>
    </ns0:profile>

</ns0:server>
```

What I really want to have in output.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">

    <extensions>
    </extensions>

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0">
        </subsystem>
    </profile>

</server>
```

I didn't show what I have modified inside the tags, since it's not really related to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, instead of `_namespace_map`, you should be using [`register_namespace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace), which is available in Python 2.7.

Comment: @mzjn I tried register_namespace. It doesn't work if you have multiple xmlns. If I do, register_namespace("", "urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1"), and then register_namespace("", "urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0"), the first one gets overrided. That way I would not have ns2, but still ns0 and ns1.

Comment: Yes, you cannot assign the same prefix (in this case an "empty prefix") to two different namespace URIs. I don't expect that to work.

Comment: Ya, I figured thats kind like a mapping thing. So instead, I used _namespace_map, which uses ns URIs as keys and prefix as values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can sometimes be very hard to make ElementTree behave exactly as wanted. My suggestion is to use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) instead, if possible.

lxml is a library similar to ElementTree, but with more features. It does not muck about with the namespace declarations.

This code parses the original XML and writes it virtually unchanged to a new file:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse("original.xml")
etree.ElementTree(doc.getroot()).write("out.xml",
                                       encoding="UTF-8",
                                       xml_declaration=True)
```